# How do I build a new project structure in netbeans using gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, netbeans

I want to create a program using youtube's api.There is a guide on youtube's web site on how to run a sample. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/java . I installed gradle and created a new project with gradle in netbeans. But then the web site says  "In your working directory, run the following commands to create a new project structure:

$ gradle init --type basic

$ mkdir -p src/main/java src/main/resources "

How do I do that? I'm guessing that is a gradle command and it creates a directory within my project but I'm not sure how to run the gradle command.

Answer (score -1):

You need to install Gradle, the easiest way is to install SDKMan and use it.
after install you can use gradle in Terminal

```
sdk install gradle 6.7.1
```

for more info

- https://sdkman.io/
- https://gradle.org/install/